# script to autosort point vaules not working

Tags: python

Trying to autosort point values from greasest to least, from .txt to .csv

Im trying to sort this: "email@email.com:stuffhere | PointsTotal = 1440"

this is what I currently got;

```
import csv
import glob
allTxtFiles = glob.glob("txt\\*.txt")
for t in allTxtFiles:
    inputFile = open(t,'r').readlines()
    endlines = []
    sortedLines = []
    for e in inputFile:
        minNum = e.split("|")
        minNum[4] = minNum[4].replace("PointsTotal = ",'')
        minNum[4] = minNum[4].strip()
        try:
            minNum[4] = int(minNum[4])
            sortedLines.append(minNum)
        except:
            endlines.append(minNum)

    sortedLines.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[4]),reverse=True)
    sortedLines.extend(endlines)

    with open("sorted\\"+t.replace("txt\\",'')+".csv",'a+',newline="") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for s in sortedLines:
            writer.writerow(s)
```

Comment: `not working` is not clear. Please explain specifically what is not working so we even have a clue of what to actually help you with.

Comment: Yeah sorry, Im trying to auto sort point vaules from greatest to least (with what im trying to sort on post) but, on executing this...nothing happens. Just trying to find where I messed up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.